# Does $\frac{1}{n}x_0$ converge to the origin in any topological vector-space?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological $\mathbf{R}$-vector-space (not necessarily Hausdorff) and $x_0 \neq 0$ a non-zero element of $X$. Then intuitively the sequence $(\frac{1}{n} x_0)_{n \in \mathbf{N}}$ converges to the origin.

This would be easy to prove, if one could show that the origin in any TVS would have a fundamental system of neighborhoods which are absorbing. But is this really correct for any TVS?

Thanks!

Comment: If $\mathbf{R}$ is considered with its usual topology, the sequence $1/n$ converges to $0$ and, since multiplication by scalar is continuous, you're done.

Comment: oh yes, you're right. well, that was easy. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $\mathbf{R}\times X\to X$, $(r,x)\mapsto x$, is continuous by assumption, with $\mathbf{R}$ given the usual topology. As a consequence, the map $\mathbf{R}\to X$, $r\mapsto rx_0$, is continuous. Since the sequence $1/n$ converges to $0$, you have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}x_0=0x_0=0
$$
Well, if $X$ is not Hausdorff, $\lim$ is used in the sense that the sequence converges to $0$ (and may converge to other points, actually to all points in the closure of $\{0\}$).